# Adding a user defined header in Laravel Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Perhaps it was my wording when searching because I new to Laravel but I am trying to figure out the most feasible way to create a user defined header script variable. My thought behind this is to be able to have an auth section of the website - /header and on that route I would be able to manage a section of the header where I can add Analytics script or any 3rd party script tag.

Thought is to include `@yield('userHeader')` in my master template.

Then in each page it should be included in just add a section

```
@section('userHeader')
  {!! $header->script !!}
@endsection
```

So I would essentially have to create a model for Header and a new DB table to house the entirety of the script tag.

Seems like it would work but I'm sure someone has done this before. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

If I do decide to do it like stated above I would essentially then have to:

```
use App\Header;
```

in each controller I would want

```
$header = Header::all();
```

Then use the following in each page. There should only be a single record in this table because there will ony be one user defined header so I am not sure that a DB table is necessary. Is this the best way to include a user defined area in the header? Will it cause any issues with security or site stability if this will include special characters?

```
@section('userHeader')
  @if(count($header) > 0)
    {!! $header->script !!}
  @endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers)

Or you can set the data in the Main Controller and access it from every controller which extends the main one. I think it will be better with View Composers

Comment: I remember seeing this section in the docs but never put it together. Thanks!